# error: 'standardToMilitary' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I have created a class, and within that class I use a function to convert standard time to military time, and I am now trying to use that function within another function that is also in the class. But every time I try to compile, it returns not declared in this scope.

Here is my main:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) { 
    ifstream in ; 
    string appData ; 
    vector<Appointment> agenda ;
    vector<Appointment> temp ; 
    in.open("agenda.txt") ; 

    if(in.fail()){
        cout << "file error" << endl ; 
    }

    while(!in.eof()){
        getline(in, appData) ; 
        if(!appData.empty()){
            agenda.push_back(appData) ;  
        } 
    }
    in.close() ; 


    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-ps") == 0){
        psFunc(agenda, temp) ; 
    } 
}
```

Here is my `.cc` file with the function that returns the error:

```cpp
void psFunc(vector<Appointment> mainVector, vector<Appointment> temp){
    int cmpr = 0 ; 
    string temp1 ; 
    string temp2 ; 
    while(mainVector.size() != temp.size()){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < mainVector.size(); i++){
            temp1 = mainVector.at(cmpr).getTime() ; 
            temp2 = mainVector.at(i).getTime() ; 
            if(standardToMilitary(temp1) < standardToMilitary(temp2)){
                continue ;
            } else if(standardToMilitary(temp1) > standardToMilitary(temp2)){
                cmpr = i ; 
            }
        }
        temp.push_back(temp1) ; 
        mainVector.erase(mainVector.begin() + cmpr) ; 
    }   
    cout << "Date" << setw(8) << "Title" << setw(30) << "Time" << setw(10) << "Duration" ; 
    cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" ; 
    for(size_t j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++){
        cout << temp.at(j).getDate() + " " + temp.at(j).getTitle() << endl ; 
    }
}
```

Here is the `standardToMilitary()`:

```cpp
int Appointment::standardToMilitary(string time){
    //reads the line for an A or a for AM and the opposite for PM, it then substr to find the hours/minutes and compiles a string
    string militaryT ; 
    int returnTime ; 
    nospaces(time) ; 
    // this section is for times with single digit hours
    if(time.length() == 6){
        if(time.substr(4, 1) == "A" || time.substr(4, 1) == "a"){
            militaryT += time[0] ;  
            militaryT += time.substr(2,2) ;
            returnTime = stoi(militaryT) ;
        } else if(time.substr(4, 1) == "P" || time.substr(4, 1) == "p"){
            militaryT += time[0] ; 
            militaryT += time.substr(2,2) ;
            returnTime = stoi(militaryT) + 1200 ;  
        }
    }
    // this section is for times with double digit hours 
    if(time.length() == 7){
        if(time.substr(0,2) == "12" && (time.substr(5,1) == "A" || time.substr(5,1) == "a")){
            militaryT += time.substr(3,2) ; 
            returnTime = stoi(militaryT) ; 
        } else if(time.substr(0,2) == "12" && (time.substr(5,1) == "P" || time.substr(5,1) == "p")){
            militaryT += "12" ; 
            militaryT += time.substr(3,2) ; 
            returnTime = stoi(militaryT) ;
        } else if(time.substr(5, 1) == "A" || time.substr(5, 1) == "a"){
            militaryT += time.substr(0,2) ;  
            militaryT += time.substr(3,2) ;
            returnTime = stoi(militaryT) ;
        } else if(time.substr(5,1) == "P" || time.substr(5,1) == "p"){
            militaryT += time.substr(0,2) ; 
            militaryT += time.substr(3,2) ;
            returnTime = stoi(militaryT) + 1200 ;  
        }
    }
    return returnTime ; 
}
```

My program is reading lines from a file, turning them into objects in the `Appointment` class, and then putting all of the objects in a `vector`. The `psFunc` is supposed to re-order the `vector` to be in order by the time, and I am trying to use the `standardToMilitary()` function to compare the times and then look for the earliest time and `push_back()` them into another `vector`.

Comment: Based on the incomplete code you've posted, it's impossible to tell whether `standardToMilitary` is in scope or not. Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. By definition, that means that the code for `standardToMilitary` would need to be in the post - a [mcve] means that we can copy/paste the code and compile it to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @KenWhite I have added the function

Comment: You added the function, but did not provide a [mcve] that can be copied, pasted and compile to reproduce the issue. Did you read the link I posted? You just dumped in more out of context code that does not allow us to see if `standardToMilitary` is in scope where you use it. A [mcve] would allow us to see that, but you've still not posted one.

Comment: You can reduce your comparisons by half, by *transforming* the string to all lower case or all upper case before comparing.  Search the internet for "c++ transform tolower".

Answer (score 2):

Your `standardToMilitary` is a non-static **member** function, and so it needs an object instance to call it:

```
Appointment a;
//...
a.standardToMilitary(/*...*/);
```

If you want to call it without an object, then make it a free standing function (move it outside of the class definition), or declare it as `static` in the class.